# jhipster registry empty pag

Tags: registry, jhipster

I have imported last version of jhipster Registry ,deploy correctly, open localhost:8761 I get a empty page, there is no error information.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @GaëlMarziou no error, I have been flushed many times

Comment: Did you run `yarn` or `yarn start`?  That's required to build the frontend, otherwise it will be blank like in your screenshot https://jhipster.github.io/jhipster-registry/#installation

Comment: @JonRuddell Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If you see a blank page when starting JHipster Registry v3+, you should run `yarn` or `yarn start` to build the frontend.

This is only necessary when building the registry from source.  When deploying the pre-built WAR or Docker image, the frontend is ready. See the [JHipster Registry](https://jhipster.github.io/jhipster-registry/#installation) docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

the environment is not compiled well. You can try to run `yarn install`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps to check the UI

**$yarn** **build** - This will build the required files for front-end

**$./mvnw**  - To run the backend after running this you will be able to see the UI is rendering on the browser.